# Laravel belongsToMany table order in insert query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, many-to-many, models

I have two models, Product and Filter.

A product can have many filters and one filter can have many products. Many to Many relationship.

In my Product I have:

```
public function filters () {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Filter');
}
```

And in my Filter:

```
public function products () {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Product')->withTimestamps();
}
```

When I try to insert a product and after save the filters like this:

```
$filtersId = $request->filter;
$product->filters()->attach($filtersId);
```

I've gotten this error:

```
Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'pontocom-moveis.filter_product' doesn't exist (SQL: insert into `filter_product` (`filter_id`, `product_id`) values (1, 31))
```

How can I change the order to product_filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter of the method is the table name.

So in this case you should use:

```
public function filters () {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Filter', 'product_filter');
}

public function products () {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Product', 'product_filter')->withTimestamps();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create the table : `filter_product` with attributes :

`filter_id`  and  `product_id`

Comment: I've already created a table for this relationship. I forgot to pass the name of relation to the belongsToMany. Thanks.